# C++ nomenclature, bind who to who?

Tags: c++

Please see this simple C++ code.

```
// rrlv1.cpp
#include <utility>
class CInt {
public: int mi;
}; 
void rrlv(CInt&& iobj) {
    int old = iobj.mi;
    iobj.mi = 4;
}

int main() {
    CInt i1{1};
    rrlv(i1);  // compile ERROR, should use std::move(i1)
    return 0;
}
```

This is bad code, but the compiler error message is interesting.

gcc-12:

```
rrlv1.cpp:13:15: error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘CInt&&’ to lvalue of type ‘CInt’
   13 |         rrlv0(i1);
      |               ^~
rrlv1.cpp:6:19: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void rrlv0(CInt&&)’
    6 | void rrlv0(CInt&& iobj) {
      |            ~~~~~~~^~~~
```

Visual C++ 2019 16.11:

```
rrlv1.cpp(13): error C2664: 'void rrlv0(CInt &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'CInt' to 'CInt &&'
rrlv1.cpp(13): note: You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference
```

Then I'm baffled, is it "bind **a variable/parameter name** to **an expression**", or the opposite?

If this is not clear, I think it would cause a huge baffle for newbies, and even communication chaos among veterans.

Which expressing method is correct (accepted by most people)?

[image: gcc vs Vc, which bind direction]

Comment: If A is bound to B, B is bound to A, isn't it? At least in this context I don't see a difference.

Comment: In my opinion, if I say bind A to B, I imply that A is a moving object, and B is something stationary. For example, "tie/bind a boat to dock". What's more, if A and B are swappable, why don't we say "bind A *with* B"?

Comment: A is an alias for B. It's like you have two names with same priority and you can always replace name A with name B. Is A an alias for B or is B an alias for A?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the standard, [under the section on initializing references](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.init.ref), it almost always talks about a reference of some kind binding to an object/expression of a value category. So from the standard perspective, GCC is more accurate.

However, if you actually look up anything that isn't deliberately trying to emulate C++ standard wording, everyone talks about objects/expressions of a value category binding to a reference of some kind. That's generally how people talk about it, particularly with regard to overload resolution for rvalue references (ie: can this expression bind to an rvalue reference).

Comment: Thank you. I agree with you. MSVC's wording "You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference" is kinda similar to saying "You cannot **convert** an lvalue to an rvalue reference". -- He'd better not use "bind" in this context.